# creating different strings in the same array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create features of text editor like - insert , delete and set. Each word in my text editor is represented by a line number. for example if I have "hi how are you" , it is represented by

```
1- hi
2- how
3- are
4- you
```

where 1, 2,3,4 represents line number(index). Here is my base code , from where I will start building the features.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct text{

    int index;
    char *word;
    } text;

    void add_word(text *t,char *word)
    {
    // adds the word at the last line
    }

    void insert(text *t, int index, char *word_to_insert)
    {
    // inserts the word at the index
    }

    int main() {

        char text[256];

        // allocates memory where all words of the text editor will be stored
        text *pointer_to_text=(text *)malloc(sizeof(text *));    

        char text_insert[256];
    while ((nextop = getchar()) != 'q') {
if (nextop == 'a') {
        new_line = strcpy(text, "hello");
        add_word(point_to_text, new_line);  
    }
if (nextop == 'i') {
       index = 5;
       new_line=strcpy(text_insert,"change");
       insert_word(point_to_text,index,new_line);
     }    

    }
        }



        return (0);
    }
```

According to this I am storing a word in `text[]` array and passing it to the `add` function. When I insert a new word I use `text_insert[]` array , store a word in it and send it to the function. By the end of insert , the index is appended with the word in `text_insert[]`. I use a pointer to refer to the address of `text_insert[]`. The pointer to this address is stored at the index where I have performed the insertion.
My question is what if I want to insert another word ? I am assuming that I would have to create a new `char array[]` and store the pointer to that `array[]` at the index.
So do I have to create a new array every time or is there a better way of doing this ? Please advice.

Comment: A general hint for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29

Comment: Can I reuse the same text_insert[] array to call insert function each time with different words in it. But the problem with that is if I do strcpy() the previous word in text_insert[] would be erased.

Comment: You need to create a linked list with `point_to_text` as the header of the list. If you know how to make a list, it is very easy. If you don't, then you have to learn. Lists are fundamental knowledge in C.

Comment: a few general problems in the code.  1) should not 'typedef' a struct.  2) MUCH easier to debug code when indentation is consistent (I prefer 4 spaces)  3) should not use tabs in source code as everyones' editor can/will interpret them as being a different size. 4) suggest keeping code block braces 'vertical', Georgian formatting (as in main()) is very difficult to read. 5) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() 6) always check the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: I need to test my insert, delete function. So I need to provide some input texts to test. But when using insert I can't use the same array again and again to send the word. I have to use a new array. What could be an alternative to this?

Comment: I tried following your question and I'm not sure I got it right but here's my take on it: new_line is simply a pointer to char (I'm not sure you need it). You have all the text saved in *pointer_to_text and use a second smaller array text[] for intermediate things(not convinced you need this either). So what you can do is simply reuse text for each new addition/insertion because it's contents become redundant after the operation....Let me know if I missed anything.